# Svg images not animating when using it in <img> tag in react

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx

So basically I am loading a svg in img tag as a loader. Image is coming up and displaying but it's not animating. If I put it in index.html it's working as expected. I expect as it is JSX something I am missing don't know what. Any lead is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If SVG image is loaded into an `<img>` tag, it will render as a static image, and its internals will not be accessible to page's javascript, and page's style definitions will not affect it.

The only way it can be animated is if the SVG itself defines its animation (aka SMIL animation). However, the support for animated SVGs is patchy (<del>IE, Edge</del>, Firefox, Chrome (considered for deprecation)).

If you want to dynamically affect your SVGs, embed them into the page directly, as `<SVG>` tags.

Comment: So I tried <svg>
            <use xlinkHref='../images/icons/loader.svg' />
          </svg> but nothing is coming up. :(

Comment: Your xlink syntax is incorrect. However, linked SVGs are almost just as useless as `<img>` - embedded ones. You need to embed them into the page code itself (either by server-side embedding or by explicitly loading and embedding them into DOM).

Comment: xlinkHref  is specific to JSX react. I will try that thanks.

Comment: If you insist on xlinking, use the following syntax: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`, and then `<use xlink:href=`

Comment: Chrome have cancelled their SMIL deprecation plans.

Answer (score 2):

Is your animated SVG self contained?  By that I mean is it using internal SMIL or CSS animation?

If so, then embedding it using `<object>` should work.  It will not animate if you embed it using `<img>`.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly presented by e-neko in one of the answers of the current question, img tag is rendered as static element. Because of that, this is how I managed to make an animated SVG be correctly rendered:

```
public render(): ReactElement {
  const { icon } = this.props;

  return (
    <svg>
      <image xlinkHref={icon}></image>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

The icon is passed as props and imported in the parent component like this:

```
import LoadingLogo from './assets/images/loading.svg';
```

I didn't manage to find any official documentation regarding this subject and this worked for me using latest React Version (16.12.0) available when posting this answer.

Cheers